# Decimal ignored when changing font size with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, font-size

I'm trying to add some text resize functionality using this code:

```
$('#text-resize a').click(function(){
    var currentValue = $('#page-body').css('fontSize');
    var currentSize = parseFloat(currentValue, 10);
    var fontUnit = currentValue.slice(-2);
    var newSize = currentSize;
    if ($(this).attr('rel') == 'decrease'){
        if (currentSize > 13){
            var newSize = currentSize / 1.2;
        }
    }
    else if ($(this).attr('rel') == 'increase'){
        if (currentSize < 19){
            var newSize = currentSize * 1.2;
        }
    }
    else {
        newSize = 1;
        fontUnit = 'em';
    }
    newSize += fontUnit;
    $('#page-body').css('fontSize', newSize);
    return false;
});
```

I know it's not the cleanest code, but my problem is that at some point (either getting or setting the font size for `#page-body` decimal points are being lost.

For example, I start with a value of 16px (from my CSS file) and when I increase it gets calculated to 19.2px. If I increase again, an alert of the currentValue (I have left out the alert) says it's 19px.

Can anyone tell me why decimal places are being ignored and how to prevent that?

If it helps, my starting CSS includes:

```
body { font-size: 16px; }
#page-body { font-size: 1em; }
```

Thanks

Comment: You're using `var` for `newSize` after it's been declared; it's not related to the problem, but it's a little odd (and inconsistently).

Comment: Thanks for spotting that Dave.

Answer (score 4):

A font size can only be a whole number of pixels, so when you set the font-size the browser casts the invalid font size to something it can use. The next time you get it, it's an integer number.

Since you're setting the font size on an element identified by ID, you should store the size in a variable and only set (never get) the element css font size.

For example, see http://jsfiddle.net/Qfzpb/

Comment: Okay, the animation earns you an upvote. As Hamish pointed out, fractional pixel values are not displayed. They can be set, but 19.4px will render as 19 and and 19.5 will render as 20. So you might as well as use whole pixel values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hamish, but your example looks like it's setting and getting the font size with decimal? What am I missing?

Comment: The CSS-specification allows floats.

Comment: @heddsta no it's not getting the css value from the element. It's only setting it over and over again, but keeping the value in the script.

Comment: @Dr.Molle you can supply a float, but the property setter will always produce an int.

Comment: No, the setter doesn't produce an int, the getter returns an int(depending on the browser)

Answer (score 2):

Sub-pixel rendering is inconsistent between browsers.

Font size can be a <length>, and a <length> is a <number> (with or without a decimal point) immediately followed by a unit identifier (e.g., px, em, etc.).
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-size-props

CSS 3 says " UAs should support reasonably useful ranges and precisions. " Open-to-interpretation wording as 'reasonable' and 'useful':
http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-values/#numeric-types

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#page-body').css('fontSize')
```

This may return different values(depending on the used browser).

Usually (in modern browsers) jQuery gets the value by using [getComputedStyle()](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSview-getComputedStyle) .
The returned value here is the value used by the browser, not the value the style-property is set to.
You may use this instead:

```
var currentValue = document.getElementById('page-body').style.fontSize
                      ||
                   $('#page-body').css('fontSize');
```

**See the fiddle to determine the differences: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/DMWhh/**