# Resizing of text ignores decimals

Tags: javascript, css

I'm having trouble with a text resizing function, I made for a project. Its purpose is to resize a number of text lines, so that they all align up, left and right inside a 400 pixel .

The issue is similar to this one: [Decimal ignored when changing font size with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981710/decimal-ignored-when-changing-font-size-with-js) but there are some differences. The authors has been using pixels - and that the solution was to use something else, since the browsers doesn't always support division of a single pixel. I use points. I also can't use jQuery because of the library file size.

Here's the code that resizes. It works like this:

> If the textwidth (span) is less than the bounding frame, increment the
>   font size by 1/10th.

```
var textobject = document.getElementById(theText);
var currentFontsize = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(textobject, null).getPropertyValue('font-size'));
while (textobject.offsetWidth < 400) {
    currentFontsize += .1;
    console.log("Width: "+textobject.offsetWidth+ " using fontsize: "+currentFontsize);
    textobject.style.fontSize = currentFontsize+"pt";
}
```

Here are my observations:

- It works in my browsers; IE, Chrome and Firefox (all updated).
- It almost works in my friend's IE, Chrome and Firefox (all updated). The width is wrong by a maximum of 6-7 pixels.
- It doesn't work satisfactory on Mac/Safari. Here, the alignment is off by 13-15 pixels.

I've peeked in the console and these are my observations:

```
Width: 372 using fontsize: 16.1
Width: 372 using fontsize: 16.2
Width: 390 using fontsize: 16.3
Width: 390 using fontsize: 16.4
Width: 390 using fontsize: 16.5
Width: 390 using fontsize: 16.6
```

As you can see, it jumps from 372 to 390 without setting a proper font size. It puzzles me that it works so differently on different machines. Any ideas on how to solve this are much appreciated!

---

**Update**: I've given up on the automatic font resizing thing and is using the GD library instead, so that all text are stored within a single bitmap. It looks promising, but there are still some [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158780/annoying-whitespace-to-the-left-when-using-the-gd-library-and-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fonts are usually not scaled linearly due to the nature of the font - they are optimized at certain sizes<sup>(1</sup>, especially screen oriented fonts<sup>(2</sup> (unless the font is of low quality).

Even if you increase the font size it may only increase slightly in height but not necessarily in width or weight, or vica verca and so on - this so it looks good and sharp at any size, especially smaller size for screen due to the screen's relative low resolutions.

The various font engines in the browser will handle this in equally various ways and try to use the closest to an optimized size so the font will look sharp (for larger sizes this is typically not a problem, but for the smaller sizes it is). It do depend very much on the font too though.

The only way, currently, to have this level of control with smaller font sizes, is to draw the text to a bitmap (ie. canvas) using a larger size, and scale that bitmap to the exact size you need (loosing selection capability etc. in the go..). But still prone to issues such as anti-aliasing.

If you specify the font size using points the size will be converted to pixels based on the system's DPI:

```
sizeInPixels = 72 / systemDPI * sizeInPoints  (ie. 72 / 96 * 16 = 12 pixels)
```

pixels are by nature integer but result may vary depending on how the browser's font engine handles sub-pixeling.

**Update**

I gave it another round and came up with a simple possible solution, though, it is not tested with various fonts so I cannot guarantee it works 100% as intended, but this uses the principle above by the means of scale transform instead of scaling a pre-filled bitmap first.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    w = canvas.width,
    lines = [
      "THIS IS HEADLINE",
      "AND THIS IS SPARTA",
      "UNDERLINE",
      "How about a little longer line?"
    ],

    //we have to guess font height as TextMetrics object is not fully implemented
    th = 30;

// setup text
ctx.font = "32px sans-serif";

for(var i = 0, line; line = lines[i]; i++) {

  var tw = ctx.measureText(line).width, // measure width of text in pixels
      s = w / tw;                       // scale based on canvas and text width
  
  ctx.translate(0, th*s);               // move line down, font heigh x scale
  ctx.scale(s, s);                      // scale canvas
  ctx.fillText(line, 0, 0);             // draw text at this scale
  ctx.scale(1/s, 1/s);                  // reset scale
}
```

```css
#canvas{border:1px solid red}
```

```html
<canvas width=500 height=240 id=canvas></canvas>
```

---

*1) Size typically refer to the height over the font and does not necessarily correspond to just the visible parts of the font but also includes any white space.

2) in the print world this is typically not an issue as prints have much higher resolutions to play with.*

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. The idea of converting the text into a bitmap could work, but I'll have to change quite a bit in the system. I also tried to fontsize the text as close to 400 pixels in width as possible and then finetuned the last pixels by changing the kerning - but as expected, no change.

Comment: @Anders thinking about it: you may be able to solve it by replacing one or two spaces in the text with a transparent image (or also here, a canvas as no loading is required) and set the width of those to compensate for the lacking pixels at the end (after finding the closest to ideal size). Just a thought.

Comment: I've worked on this, over and over - the replacement of spaces with images will not cut it, since the text often only consists of one word, like "Electrical" (line 1) "Engineer" (line 2).

However, I made a promising piece of code that uses the GD Image library as you suggested - and it almost works, please see the update in a couple of minutes

Comment: @Anders I updated my answer with an example code which may or may not solve the problem (the "may not" as I haven't tested with many fonts).

Comment: btw: The only way to remove those white spaces on either side is to first draw the text to bitmap, scan the edges pixel by pixel to find min/max region. clip draw that back to main bitmap using scale as above.

Comment: Hello Ken. First of all, thank you for your efforts in order to help me out - much appreciated. However, I decided to follow your other advice, regarding text-to-image conversion and it was quite a challenge to get it right but I managed to get it workingy in the end: [link to another question, I asked yesterday, but managed to sort out.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158780/annoying-whitespace-to-the-left-when-using-the-gd-library-and-text/27160367#27160367)